# When sending data in JSON format, is it with or without square brackets?

Tags: javascript, json

I am sending data in JSON format over the server.

Currently, I am having issues with `flask.jsonify()`, but that isn't part of this question.

I am using Marshmallow to try and help me return data in JSON format. Using  `marshmallow.Schema.dump(query)` it outputs something like this:

```
[{'id': 1, 'title': 'title', 'content': 'some content'},
 {'id': 2, 'title': 'another title', 'content': 'some more content'},
 ...]
```

Now, my question is whether a JavaScript file is expecting the content with or without the square brackets.
I am pretty sure it is supposed to be without the square brackets, which `flask.jsonify()` is designed to remove, correct?

Comment: That is an array of objects, which requires the enclosing square brackets

Comment: `marshmallow.Schema.dump` does not promise to output any valid JSON. In fact, the single quotes are not valid for a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend sticking to standard JSON whenever possible; https://www.json.org/json-en.html

A file containing only comma separated values is not valid JSON. There must be square brackets to indicate that, at the top level, your JSON document consists of a single array.